# does p2p filesharing need a static ip

Tags: p2p

Ok. I am creating a teamviewer like app. And p2p connection is the best route based on my research on p2p. I want to know weather teamviewer works fully on p2p, and is it possible to create such an app without using any dedicated server and a static public ip address. I mean i do know all nodes in a p2p n/w act equal, but then how will these maintain a connection having dynamic ip addresses. Hoping someone can explain how p2p establishes this.

Answer (score 0):

They do not need a static IP. But in absence of a static IP you need some discovery / address exchange mechanism that allows nodes to find each other.

Overlay networks like DHTs/gossip protocols/supernodes are generally used for such a thing, but it could be as simple as a user manually entering the current IP address.

In practice reachability is a much bigger concern. NATs and Firewalls may prevent incoming connections. If both nodes cannot accept incoming connections then neither can connect to the other.

Comment: So it is possible right, like teamviewer. I only need a mech. that would exchange the ip addresses(dynamic) b/w them.